# How to make Angular Material dialog persists its absolute position

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Material dialog in my project to display list of options.
Material dialog blocks the scroll bar of the page by defaul.
When I have a lot of options to display some of the items might fall out of the screen and in order to see them you need to scroll down, hence I had to make the scrolling bar avaiable using `scrollStrategy`.

However if a user clicks on the options button, then scroll down or up the dialog will be always on the screen and doesn't move with scrolling direction to keep its absolute position (under the triggering button) so my question how can I change this?

I have created a small angular project to demonstrate my issue;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpatij

Comment: Right now your [mcve] doesn't reproduce the behavior you describe. Could you please update it to show the issue in action ?

Comment: Because it's not absolute positioned, it has `position: fixed`.

Comment: @Maryannah
I've updated my example by adding another options button at the bottom of the page.
If open the example again and try to click on the second options button you will not be able to see the rest of options as I removed the `scrollStrategies.noop()` .

Comment: What do "the rest of options" represent here ? I can see both options in your example.

Comment: @Maryannah
What I mean with "the rest of options" the rest of dialog items.
in my example there's only 2 options: 1. save 2. share

Comment: And both are visible. So what's your issue exactly ?

Comment: @ritaj
That's true, the dialog contaier has fixed position, if you change that to something else then scroll down you will notice that clicking on a part of background won't close the dialog.

Comment: @Maryannah
Try to not to scroll please, then click on the secon options button.

Comment: If I do not scroll, I can not click on the second button, as it isn't reachable (small resolution)

Comment: @Maryannah 
Have a look at Ronald Korze answer to see the issue, or try to keep the second optition button at the bottom of the page not in the center.

Comment: Let the dialog position itself. Your `updateTooltipPosition` function is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem you mean that, because you don't use the default position of the dialog (centered) but instead position it at about the button position, the dialog is cut off?

Actually in my opinion best solution would be just to use the default positioning of the material dialog where dialog appears centered.[image]

Comment: I am using the material dialog as context overlay (tooltip).

Comment: maybe a bit questionayble :) why not a real tooltip, or (if you need to place some actions), or an expansion panel?